# How Restrict user to upload document to SharePoint

Tags: document-library

In my case i have 20 country and in 20 country many company i want to restrict users on the basis of country and company.

1. if the user from India and there are 5 company(a,b,c,d) in India and user company is c so user upload the document inside Document Library/India/a ,only that particular folder .if user login from India and any xyz company(User) so he see only his company folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.

You ideal solution should use different sub sites for country and different folder for each company. Create groups like India_CompanyA and India_CompanyB etc. Break Document library permission and provide permission to group accordingly.

If you still need to use single document library. You would need to use item level permission and create groups for each country like mentioned above, and provide permission to group at folder level.

So at high level do the following.

- Create all required groups according to Country and Company, ideally
  you will have number of groups equal to number of companies across
  country.
- Create folders in document library accordingly with Country at root
  level and sub folders for each company inside country folder.
- Break permissions of each folder by stop inheriting permission and
  applying folder level permission to group.

You can follow this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6) for changing permission for folder

Side note - If your documents inside are going to be more than 5000 items, you should avoid item level permission (though you are applying permission at folder level)

Comment: hi Siddharth Vaghasia can you guide me how i can do that because i am new in sharepoint

Comment: already mentioned design in answer...let me know if you are looking for anything specific..